# How to create procedure to run different queries in a single go

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have following different working queries running separately and I want to run all of these in a single go with some stored procedure or any available method in PostGreSQL.

```
 SELECT obu_id, trip_id, start_time, end_time, end_time - LEAD(start_time)     OVER(PARTITION       BY obu_id ORDER BY start_time) AS diff FROM clean_trips_byobu;
```

Next Query

```
 UPDATE clean_trips_byobu c

 SET    dwell_time = COALESCE(u.diff, interval '-1 hour')

 FROM (SELECT obu_id, trip_id, start_time, end_time,end_time - lead(start_time) OVER   (PARTITION BY obu_id                ORDER BY start_time) AS diff FROM  clean_trips_byobu) u

WHERE (c.obu_id, c.trip_id, c.start_time, c.end_time)
 =(u.obu_id, u.trip_id, u.start_time, u.end_time)

 AND c.dwell_time IS DISTINCT FROM COALESCE(u.diff, interval '-1 hour');
```

Next Query

```
 UPDATE public.clean_trips_byobu
 SET trip_dist = clean_trips.bktp_mt_total
 FROM public.clean_trips
 WHERE public.clean_trips.obu_id = clean_trips_byobu.obu_id
 AND clean_trips.bktp_trip_id = clean_trips_byobu.trip_id;
```

I want to include all these queries in one function or procedure.

Thanks

Comment: Well you did mention stored procedure, hint hint.

Comment: you answered your own question...just put them into a stored proc.. if you wanted to keep them separate then you could put them in their own individual stored procs and then use another to exec each of them

Comment: @DanBracuk I don't know what exactly will work here, As far as I know I need to crate some type of procedure. Do I need to edit the question?

Comment: No you need to google PostGreSQl Create Procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Write a stored procedure and write all the queries there in that stored procedure after begin

Comment: While correct, in its current form this answer probably should be a comment (like Dan's). OP seems to have no idea where to begin. The answer would be improved by suggesting a few links and hints to get him started.

Comment: If you want to know how to write then refer to this link http://forums.asp.net/t/1722262.aspx/1